# selecting some form inputs and show it to the user

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to be able to select only required fields and show it to my frontend, this is the html template.
create_employee.html

```
      {% for field in form %}
          <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6">
                      {{ field }}
                  </div>
              </div>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
              <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I did something like `{{ field.first_name }}` but this does not show first name  form input but if I use `{{ field }}` all the fields are shown up even the ones I don't want the user to see.
How can I select only the fields I want to return to the user?

forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(BSModalModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
class CreateEmployeeView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'payrolls/create_employee.html'
    form_class = EmployeeForm
    success_message = 'Success: Employee created'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('payrolls:all_employees')
```

Comment: Can you share your form code and describe which fields should not be shown? If a field should not be shown to the user then removing the field from your form or giving it the HiddenInput widget would be appropriate

Comment: I have edited the questions and added the form

Comment: Could just pass the fields you want to `EmployeeForm.Meta.fields`? `fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', ...]`

Comment: the reason why I do not pass the the fields like is during the creation of an employee not all fields are show but during update of an employee, all fields are show

Comment: Create two forms, one for creation and one for update, only specify the required fields on the creation form

Comment: ok that makes sense but what of if I want field inputs in two columns ? eg
first_name                       last_name

Comment: could you please post your views function/class that renders this form?

Comment: @B.Anup I have edited the question and added the views snippet.

Comment: What is this "BSModalCreateView" that you are inheriting in your "createEmployeeView"?
If you have defined "BSModalCreateView", could you please post the code of it. I tried with "CreateView" and I am able to render the fields as expected. 
I used "class CreateEmployeeView(CreateView)". Give it a try with "CreateView", if you have inherited wrong view while defining View class